# Android - Launch a popup window by touching a canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, popup, touch

I'm trying to launch a custom popup window when I touch coordinates on a canvas.  I'm drawing on an image of a field, and I need the popup to appear around the coordinate I touch on the field.

I'm unable to launch the popup from within the DrawingView class (where I draw on the image) because I don't have the Activity for the popup function.  And if I try to launch the popup from the necessary activity (FieldPage), the DrawingView touch event overrides the FieldPage touch event.  In this case, I can create the popup whenever I touch the grey background behind the buttons, but not on the green field image I'm using.  I'd attach a picture but don't have the reputation.

Here's the code for FieldPage:

```
public class FieldPage extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.field_page);
}

// The method that displays the popup.
private void showPopup(final Activity context, int xPos, int yPos) { //Point p) { //
   int popupWidth = 800;
   int popupHeight = 800;

   // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
   LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popout_layout, viewGroup);

   // Creating the PopupWindow
   final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
   popup.setContentView(layout);
   popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
   popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
   popup.setFocusable(true);

   // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
   int OFFSET_X = 0; //30;
   int OFFSET_Y = 0; //30;

   // Clear the default translucent background
   popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

   // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
   popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x, p.y);  //xPos + OFFSET_X, yPos + OFFSET_Y);

   // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
   Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
   close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
       popup.dismiss();
     }
   });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int touchX = (int) event.getX();
    int touchY = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            showPopup(FieldPage.this, touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}

//Popup function
private void showPopup(final Activity context, int xPos, int yPos) { 
   int popupWidth = 800;
   int popupHeight = 800;

   // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
   LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popout_layout, viewGroup);

   // Creating the PopupWindow
   final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
   popup.setContentView(layout);
   popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
   popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
   popup.setFocusable(true);

   // Clear the default translucent background
   popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

   // Displaying the popup at the specified location
   popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x, p.y); 

   // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
   Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
   close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
       popup.dismiss();
     }
   });
}
```

DrawingView code:

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

private Path drawPath;
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
private int paintColor = 0xFFFF0000;
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap, mutableBitmap;

public DrawingView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

private void setupDrawing() {
    //Sets up various paths and my canvas
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.field);
    mutableBitmap = canvasBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {      
    canvas.drawBitmap(mutableBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int touchX = (int) event.getX();
    int touchY = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //Draw Stuff
            //This is where I tried launching the popup
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //Stuff
            break;
        default:
            return false;

    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: you need to add popup open in custom view touch event not in activity it self

Comment: @mohammed momn, I had it in the DrawingView class previously.  I can't then call it from DrawingView because I can't access the FieldPage class, but if I try to call it from FieldPage, nothing happens.